# What are some high brightness monitors?

Tags: monitors, displays

I've been trying to find and purchase a monitor that has more than 500 nits, but that seems to be about where normal monitors top out at. I've looked a little bit at outdoor monitors and displays, but those tend to have price ranges that are out of this world for consumers and further, one that I bought, I found only has a brightness of 500 nits (advertised). The difference between the indoor and outdoor monitors appears to be the anti-reflection coating and weatherproofing done on them. Neither of these things do I really need when I just want a super bright monitor.

Does anyone know of a monitor with **higher than** 500 nits? Also, as a soft boarder, under $1000 dollars would be ideal.

Comment: My knowledge on this area is pretty slim, but you could potential buy a brighter backlight replacement bulb and replace it.  Now I don't know if you would run into incompatibilities or power consumption problems if you tried something like that.  Personally I would be looking for an LCD screen with an LED backlight, I would think you could easily get more nits for cheaper. (This may be too crazy, but buy a super cheap one and replace the CCFL with an LED light bar) Hopefully a pro can follow me up

Comment: @Timmy thanks. That's what my other question I posted is for: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/what-are-some-high-contrast-ratio-displays
That would be my second choice, but without high contrast ability, I figure a brighter backlight would just wash colors out.

Answer (score 1):

The closest things I've found is a 1500nit outdoor display:
Samsung OM24E - 24"
Model: OM24E
1500nit rating
[Samsung 24" Full HD LED-LCD Commercial Digital Signage Display, Black](http://www.staples.com/Samsung-24-inch-Full-HD-LED-LCD-Commercial-Digital-Signage-Display-Black/product_IM12U7561?cid=PS:GooglePLAs:IM12U7561&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=IM12U7561&KPID=IM12U7561&cvosrc=PLA.google-SALES.Computer%20Accessories%20%26%20Peripherals&cvo_crid=39357180702&cvo_campaign=71700000015225244&gclid=Cj0KEQiA_eXEBRDP8fnIlJDXxsIBEiQAAGfyoWZgiL-7fRGhOOKwIf27kz3Zq2J99SVjKAh2MDnltIYaAr8j8P8HAQ)
Most shops selling this seem to have this only on special order so once you order it, there's no going back.

Other than that, the best I've found are very expensive radiology displays. The cheaper versions come in black/white and/or grayscale. They tend to have poor resolution unless you want to spend a fortune. You still have to look closely to see if they actually have a higher than 500nit brightness, but I've seen many that do.